# Unable to open Wikipedia app on Android TV

Tags: chrome-for-android, android-tv, smart-tv, wiki

I have Mi TV 4a pro and I want to open Wikipedia app on it. **I had installed Wikipedia app on TV via pendrive** but when I open the app it crashes. Is there is any way?

Further I had installed chrome browser on TV and when I search on it then it works fine and show results. But how can I open the links? **Like when I search "mathematics", it shows Wikipedia link in results but how do I open that link?** (As I have TV remote not a mouse to click on link)  Please help.

Comment: You should check the Play Store for the Wikipedia app from the TV box directly to see if the app is compatible for your Android TV. *Not all apps are compatible with Android TV*. As for the second question, usually there are navigation buttons on the TV remote as a replacement to point-and-click.

Comment: @AndrewT. Sir, wiki app isn't available on play store (given in TV ). Only limited apps are available. Though I had downloaded a browser named puffin, from which I can open different sites including wiki too. But that browser doesn't support save pages options for offline viewing. Is there any browser available in Android TV play store which can save pages for offline viewing? ( Wikipedia app can save articles! But not working on TV :-( )

Comment: Explicit app recommendation questions is off-topic here, but there is an SE site for that: Software Recommendations. However, please follow their [strict question guideline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) to ensure that you get the app you want.